# Whether or not to merge Bootstrap and jQuery UI

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I have a question: is merge Bootstrap and jQuery UI a good way? Maybe better use some plugins for Bootstrap to have Datepicker, Autocomplite?
Or using Bootstrap and jQuery UI (https://jquery-ui-bootstrap.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/#block-documentation for example) more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI bootstrap offers a lot of widgets which are not available in bootstrap. You can use it otherwise you'll need a separate plugin for every feature you want to add. It's nod so bad. You can give it a shot.